# Tag naming conventions

Tags: discussion, tagging

We should make an effort to keep tags fairly uniform in their construction.  I'm thinking:

- Actions with a proper `-tion` noun form should use that form (naviga*tion*, water-purifica*tion*)
- Actions without should be a gerund (camp*ing*, hik*ing*, sail*ing*).
- Nouns with a plural *that makes sense as a tag* should be pluralized (boot*s*, emergenc*ies*, river*s*).

Exceptions:

- [nature](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nature)
- [fire](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire)

  - Can be either collective or discrete, I suggest we keep the collective (singular).

Ones I'm not sure about:

- [disease](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disease)
- [climate](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate)

If you come across a tag that doesn't fit this, fix it.
If you have a suggestion, please do post it and we'll discuss.

Answer (score 5):

Important quote from the [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) article

> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might
>   think.
>
> If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a
>   meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as
>   the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective],
>   and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you
>   nothing at all about the content of the question. If the tag commonly
>   means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.
>   In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself …
>   is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner].
>   Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are
>   impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective
>   metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and
>   [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

Comment: Yes, a good thing to note.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your suggestion is mostly summed up with "use nouns; plural form if possible".

I think that's a good guideline, but you probably don't need to maintain a list of all possible exceptions if you phrase it that way. :)

And of course, do your best to avoid creating [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), whether they conform to these guidelines or not.