# Can't create a [snakes] tag

Tags: support, tagging

I tried to retag [a question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/282/46) with the tag [snakes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snakes) ([plural as suggested here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24/46)).

But I'm getting the following error:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Creating the new tag [snakes] is not allowed since the tag [snake]
>   already exists. If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it
>   on meta.

However, there are no [questions tagged as snake](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snake). What should I do?

Comment: Why did it have to be [snakes]...

Comment: @GraceNote Uniformity, I guess, the meta topic I'm linking to suggests that nouns with a plural should be pluralized.

Comment: @Psy I believe grace note was alluding to the movie *Snakes on a Plane*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I renamed the tag as [snakes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snakes); although, it is not currently being used and will be deleted automatically this evening if nothing is tagged as such.

Answer (score 3):

I believe unused tags vanish after a day or two of not being used, so wait until it dies, then retag.  Otherwise, I think a mod may be able to switch.