# How to discuss tags in a proper way?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noted, that there are a lot of discussions on individual tags here on the great outdoors meta. I also noted that there are a lot of strange tags, synonyms and tags not accomplying to the conventions (do we have a [convention](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/tag-naming-conventions)?).

I would like to discuss:

- How to discuss tags - using individual questions for each tag on meta, some kind of wiki or ...?
- How to flag obviously synonymous tags (like [us](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us) and [united-states](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)) so somebody with (I think) more than 1.250 rep can suggest them for merging ?
- Do we want tags as least common denominator or to point to everything related to that topic?

Also, do you consider the above mentioned convention as approved? Do we need a more detailed convention for tagging than the general SE rules?

I am sorry about posting so many questions at once - I think they should be answered coherently since they interact. Please feel free to edit if you don´t agree how I asked about this topic.

Comment: Somehow related (to the last bullet):
[Excess tags for related topics?](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/217/excess-tags-for-related-topics)

Comment: See the [Tagging section of the SE FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: "How to flag obviously synonymous tags" is answered [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you mean by *How to discuss tags*? Can you elaborate? Normally discussions like this would happen on Meta.

Comment: I've re-tagged all the [tag:us] to [tag:united-states]. The US tag should be deleted in due course.

Comment: @Liam: thanks to the merging. I am aware of the rules for Tag-synonyms. Still, whats if I (as an user who can´t create synonyms) want to create OBVIOUS tag synonyms? Do I have to put a request on META, or do we want a wiki for that? Because I can´t do anything specific about that. Maybe we should request a feature so we can just flag them.

Comment: @Liam: concerning "how to discuss...": I am unsure if the way tag discussions are currently done is the only and/or best way possible. Maybe there is something else possible than opening a question for every tag. This may be appropriate if there is a discussion, but to make a good cleanup on tags it doesn´t seem appropriate.

Comment: The issue is, all SE sites work on the principal that you have to earn power. Which is why only certain rep users can affect things like this. It stops the system being abused by spammers, etc. The creation of Synonyms is not encouraged. Eventually tags and their synonyms are merged into a single tag. This is more a system to prevent repetition than to try and cover every conceivable variation on a theme. So you shouldn't create a synonym tag if a tag that roughly fits already exists.

Comment: BTW, I didn't merge. I literally edited each question and changed the tag.

Comment: @Liam: So next time I run over a synonym like [tag:us] and [tag:united-states] I post it as a question on meta? Well, thats what I call overkill. I´m not asking for the right to merge them, I am asking for a flag-feature to bring this to the attention of a mod without putting a question here. I am not allowed to close questions, but I can flag them - it would be possible to do so for tags as well and I don´t see any reason why flagging should be a good way to bring questions (or answers, or comments) to mods attention but not bad tags.

Comment: @Liam: But then it will just show up again as new users use [tag:us] because they are not aware of the other tag. Thats whats synonyms are for.

Comment: Eventually empty tags are deleted by the system. I think this topic is less of an issue than you think. If a tag synonym is around for a bit. It's not the end of the world. If you feel the SE system should change then you should raise it on http://meta.stackexchange.com/. That's the site that is responsible for SE functionality. I would be surprised if this changes though.

Answer (score 5):

Discuss tags here on meta.

Technically synonyms can be made by users, but it's difficult and almost never happens, even on the bigger sites. Post about it here on meta and a mod will deal with it.

As for tagging questions, that's a bit less clear-cut. Try not to create new tags unless they're absolutely necessary; add tags you think will help users find the question when they're searching for it.