# What does the community think of the outdoor-gadgets tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a new [outdoor-gadgets](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outdoor-gadgets) tag, and I'm wondering how the community feels about it. It only has two questions so far, which is why it seems to be worth thinking about now. Both of the questions are very popular and well-written, so that's not the point of this at all!

In [Are there any situations while backpacking that would require a watch?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15370/are-there-any-situations-while-backpacking-that-would-require-a-watch), it's used together with [safety](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) and [backpacking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backpacking). Obviously it's referring to the watch.

In [What role does information about atmospheric pressure play from an outdoor perspective?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15411/what-role-does-information-about-atmospheric-pressure-play-from-an-outdoor-pers), it's the only tag. I thought about adding some more tags to that question, but didn't want to do that yet.

According to [this](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-to-discuss-tags-in-a-proper-way/490#490), meta is the place to bring this up, so I wanted to do this first.

My questions are:

- Is that a valid tag?
- Would it be easily searchable, especially if used alone? Since that's one of the main purposes of tags, I'm not sure it would help the community in general, unless of course a lot of questions start using it, in which case it would appear more frequently in searches.
- If it is valid, how should it be used? For instance, we have [binoculars](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binoculars), [compasses](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compasses), [gps](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps), and others which could be called outdoor gadgets. In general, those are used with broader category tags, like [gear](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gear), [hiking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiking), [navigation](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation).
- Is it a meta tag? To my inexperienced eye, that's what it looks like. In which case, we're discouraged from adding those.

To those who are using it, please don't take any offense. I can definitely see the point. I bump into this frequently when asking my questions, and I'm often tempted to add something new. We have a lot of generic questions that seemingly could be helped by new tags like this to narrow them down. I'm just seeking advice about this one.

Comment: Personally, I think this question is jumping the gun, let's wait until we get more questions tagged with it and then see if it should be named something else or removed.

Comment: Gut reaction is it should be made a synonym to "gear," but I also think we should give some time before making a final call.

Comment: I'm not clear on when a piece of gear becomes trivial enough to be a gadget.

Comment: @ab2 I agree, or what the difference is. That's why I have the same gut reaction as cobaltduck that it should be a synonym of gear. I also still think it doesn't stand well as the only tag in the second question I mentioned. I think other tags would increase the ability to search for an interesting question like that. I've been waiting to see if one of the people using the tag might submit a description for it. That might help for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @ab2 well if the good [Inspector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspector_Gadget) is our example something as complicated and non-trivial as an [ultralight helicopter that attaches to your head](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-JHfXVlkik) can be classified as a gadget... ;)

Comment: @Erik Attached to my head?  I want it attached to my pack!

Comment: @ab2 lol that's a position I've sympathized with many times. :)

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh I posted an answer advocating it be removed. In my opinion if we're just going to end up deleting the tag there is no point waiting until the job is bigger. I'd rather clean up a small mess than wait for it to grow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one has written an answer to this question yet I'll post my feelings.

**I think that tag should go away**, because I don't see how it adds any value to existing tags. *Everything here* should pertain to the "outdoors" so the first part of the tag doesn't add any value. Anything that can be described as a "gadget" can also be described as a piece of [gear](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gear). Since the first part of the tag is pointless and the second part is a clear synonym I vote we [burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/301021) [outdoor-gadgets](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outdoor-gadgets).

If we think it might get recreated then I feel it should be merged with [gear](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gear) to prevent its rebirth.

Comment: Yes, and do it yesterday!

Comment: Thanks Erik, my thoughts exactly!

Comment: I re-tagged everything with outdoor-gadgets to gear.  I believe that should kill the now empty tag within about 24 hours.  If it gets recreated we can merge it.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Thanks!

Comment: I have validated that outdoor-gadgets does not show as an option when typing tags in a question, If it is recreated someone would have to recreate it.