# March 2018 tag rename requests

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

**Update:**

The reason I am asking for this is **because it's much easier and less irritating all around if the mods do the tag merges.**

If I were to **manually retag the equipment-care to gear-care it would take me 50-60 edits and clutter up the home page.** If a mod makes a tag synonym, it is taken care of automatically.

I have a bunch of tag name requests for the mods to take care of and so I thought I would write them all out in one place since its easier than raising a bunch of flags and less prone to miscommunication.

Renames mostly to make them consistent with [our naming convention](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24/8794) and some to make them sound better.

Old -> new

- czech -> czech-republic
- top-rope -> top-roping
- backpack -> backpacks
- canoe -> canoes
- bear-bag -> bear-bags
- tarp-tent -> tarp-tents
- ice-axe -> ice-axes
- boots-b2 -> b2-boots
- bike -> bikes
- allergic -> allergies
- zebra -> zebras
- kayak -> kayaks
- sleeping-pad -> sleeping-pads
- rattlesnake -> rattlesnakes

Tags to merge

equipment-care -> gear-care

as equipment was merged into gear quite a while ago.

Comment: Now that I know this process wouldn't bump all the questions to the front page, I feel better. I like uniformity, especially in certain cases. In fact, I found another that I think would be a good addition to the list. I'd like to ask you to wait some days/weeks before doing anything, though, so people have time to check this out and weigh in. Plenty of people don't come to meta that often, and later wish they had voted, whether up or down. Also, once a big project's done, the mod(s) may not want to do it again.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the proposed changes (except that I find equipment vastly superior to gear, but that's flogging a dead horse). I just have my usual laisser-faire stance: This is so minor that while it would be nice if it did happen, it might just be too much work for the gain (for mod(s), which on TGO is the same as Rory). And manually retagging is in my opinion a bad idea, not only for time wasted, which is everyone's own decision, but because of bumping questions "randomly" to the top.

Comment: For what it's worth, I like equipment better too!